# Is "ask questions without hesitance" a correct phrase?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, word-usage

more specifically, I was corrected when using "...without hesitance" and was asked to change it to "... without hesitation". Now I am confused. Was I wrong to say "ask questions without hesitance"?

To be even more exact. It was mentioned as a suggestion or a goal. For example:

```
Goals for Tom: Ask questions without hesitance
```

Which I was made to change to:

```
Goals for Tom: Ask questions without hesitation
```

After searching the internet a little bit, I think that they are synonyms so they should be interchangeable right? Or atleast interchangeable in that context? Basically what I want to know is was what I wrote downright wrong or in any need of correction?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's wrong, but *hesitance* is a fairly rare word. Here are some results from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

> HESITATION:    2686
>
> HESITANCE: 57

The numbers are the number of hits. We can see that *hesitance* is much less common than *hesitation*. Let's try searching for *without hesitation / hesitance*:

> WITHOUT HESITATION: 807
>
> WITHOUT HESITANCE: 0

We can see that *without hesitance* is not something that people say very often if at all.

I have to say, my first thought when I saw *without hesitance* in your title was that it looked weird, but like I said, I don't think it's wrong. It's up to you: you can use it if you like, but you will risk sounding weird.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.onelook.com/?w=hesitance&ls=a

**The word *HESITANCE* is found in 12 dictionaries. You were right when you used it.**

Comment: I see, that's a start. What is your opinion on the phrase then?